# how to recall last argument in bash with vi setting

Tags: bash, command-line, keyboard-shortcuts, vi

I use `set -o vi` setting in bash. The shorcut `Alt+.` (recalling last argument of previous command) here doesn't work as in emacs mode, so what is the equivalent for vi?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this line after `set -o vi`:

```
bind -m vi-command ".":yank-last-argument # or insert-last-argument
```

Then you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> like in emacs-mode.

Or use history expansion, working in both:

```
!$:p
```

Comment: It does output the last command parameter but does not cycle through all last used command parameters, like emacs mode does.

In vi mode you'll always get the last parameter over and over. It doesn't help much.

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rluserman.html#SEC13), the correct command is `yank-last-arg`.

Comment: @jasonwryan: They're synonym. See: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Miscellaneous-Commands.html#Miscellaneous-Commands.

Answer (score 11):

There are various method to get the last argument of last command:

### 1. inputrc: insert-last-argument & yank-last-arg

Copy the following code into your `~/.inputrc` file

```
set editing-mode vi
# Insert Mode
set keymap vi-insert
"\e.":yank-last-arg
"\e_": yank-last-arg
```

You can use [my inputrc file](https://github.com/Marslo/mylinux/blob/master/Configs/HOME/inputrc/.inputrc_bash#L45). And here the inputrc manual for [`insert-last-argument`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-insert_002dlast_002dargument-_0028M_002d_002e-or-M_002d_005f_0029) and [`yank-last-arg`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-yank_002dlast_002darg-_0028M_002d_002e-or-M_002d_005f_0029)

### 2. Word Designators: !!:$ & !$

For example:

```
┌─ (marslo@MarsloJiao ~) ->
└─ # echo arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5
arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5

┌─ (marslo@MarsloJiao ~) ->
└─ # echo !$
echo arg5
arg5

┌─ (marslo@MarsloJiao ~) ->
└─ # echo arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5
arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5

┌─ (marslo@MarsloJiao ~) ->
└─ # echo !!:$
echo arg5
arg5

┌─ (marslo@MarsloJiao ~) ->
└─ # echo arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5
arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5

┌─ (marslo@MarsloJiao ~) ->
└─ # echo !!:^
echo arg1
arg1

┌─ (marslo@MarsloJiao ~) ->
└─ # echo arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5
arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5

┌─ (marslo@MarsloJiao ~) ->
└─ # echo !!:2-4
echo arg2 arg3 arg4
arg2 arg3 arg4
```

The manual of [Shell Word Designator](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Designators) shows:

> !!:$
>
> ```
> designates the last argument of the preceding command. This may be shortened to !$.
> ```
>
> 0 (zero)
>
> ```
> The 0th word. For many applications, this is the command word.
> ```
>
> n
>
> ```
> The nth word.
> ```
>
> ^
>
> ```
> The first argument; that is, word 1.
> ```
>
> $
>
> ```
> The last argument.
> ```
>
> %
>
> ```
> The word matched by the most recent ‘?string?’ search.
> ```
>
> x-y
>
> ```
> A range of words; ‘-y’ abbreviates ‘0-y’.
> ```
>
> *
>
> All of the words, except the 0th. This is a synonym for ‘1-$’. It is not an error to use ‘*’ if there is just one word in the event; the empty string is returned in that case.
>   x*
>
> ```
> Abbreviates ‘x-$’
> ```
>
> x-
>
> ```
> Abbreviates ‘x-$’ like ‘x*’, but omits the last word.
> ```

### 3. Shell Special Parameters: $_

For example:

```
┌─ (marslo@MarsloJiao ~) ->
└─ # echo very-very-very-very-very-long-argument
very-very-very-very-very-long-argument

┌─ (marslo@MarsloJiao ~) ->
└─ # echo $_
very-very-very-very-very-long-argument

┌─ (marslo@MarsloJiao ~) ->
└─ # ls /usr/local/etc/

┌─ (marslo@MarsloJiao ~) ->
└─ # cd $_

┌─ (marslo@MarsloJiao /usr/local/etc) ->
└─ #
```

In the manual of [Shell Special Parameters](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters):

> _
>
> (An underscore.) At shell startup, set to the absolute pathname used to invoke the shell or shell script being executed as passed in
>   the environment or argument list. Subsequently, expands to the last
>   argument to the previous command, after expansion. Also set to the
>   full pathname used to invoke each command executed and placed in the
>   environment exported to that command. When checking mail, this
>   parameter holds the name of the mail file.